# Could not dynamic items in two dimensions array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to add dynamic items in two dimension array,

Now i have have that array like below,

```
private static final Object[][] DATA = { { "One", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Two", Boolean.FALSE },
            { "Three", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Four", Boolean.FALSE }, { "Five", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Six", Boolean.FALSE },
            { "Seven", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Eight", Boolean.FALSE }, { "Nine", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Ten", Boolean.FALSE },
            { "One", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Two", Boolean.FALSE }, { "Three", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Four", Boolean.FALSE },
            { "Five", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Six", Boolean.FALSE }, { "Seven", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Eight", Boolean.FALSE },
            { "Nine", Boolean.TRUE }, { "Ten", Boolean.FALSE } };
```

Instead of this i want to add each item **{ "Nine", Boolean.TRUE }** dynamically. Could you please suggest me an idea to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`

Comment: a) Unclear what you mean by dynamically. b) This is a terrible use of arrays. Use a set or map instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you need this steps :

Create an array of numbers :

```
String[] numbers = {"One", "Two", "Three", ...};
```

Loop over this array and check if the index in even or not it yes use `Boolean.TRUE` else use `Boolean.FALSE`

```
String[] numbers = {"One", "Two", "Three", ...};
Object[][] data = new Object[numbers.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        data[i] = new Object[]{numbers[i], Boolean.TRUE};
    } else {
        data[i] = new Object[]{numbers[i], Boolean.FALSE};
    }
}
```

If you use :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
```

The output is :

```
[[One, true], [Two, false], [Three, true], ...]
```

---

But this is not the better way you store values, instead you can create your own Object which can have two parameters String and Boolean :

```
class MyObject{
   String n;
   Boolean;
   ...
}
```